# How to print a tuple from view to html

Tags: html, django

I am woking in Django and I would simply like to print a tuple from view to html. Like so:

VIEW.PY

```
def dumdum_view(request):
        dummy =[(1,2,3)]
        dumdum = tuple(dummy)
return render_to_response('dumdum.html', {'dumdum':dumdum})
```

HTML.PY

```
{% for i in dumdum %}
     {{ i.0 }} {{ i.1}} {{ i.2 }}
{% endfor %}
```

I have tried various variations of the simple code above but nothing works.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing a nested tuple inside a list and then you are converting that list to a tuple itself. The result of your code is a tuple of tuples.

Simplify the code by declaring a tuple initially and pass it to your Django template.

Working example:

views.py

```
def dumdum_view(request):
    dummy = (1,2,3)
    context = {"dummy": dummy}
    return render_to_response('dumdum.html', context)
```

Django Template:

```
{% for x in dummy %}
     {{x}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py

```py
def dumdum_view(request):
    dummy = (1,2,3)
    context = {"dummy": dummy}
    return render_to_response('dumdum.html', context)
```

and on your template

```py
{% for x in dummy %}
     {{ x }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dummy data is a list of tuple then you just need to change your view to:

```
#list of tuples
dummy =[(1,2,3)]
return render_to_response('dumdum.html', {'dumdum':dummy})
```

And your template can remain the same